# Performing 100k iterations in less than 4 seconds

Tags: java, performance, time, hashmap

I need to iterate a `HashMap` containing integers for `10^5` turns. I generate integers randomly. Then, I perform required arithmetic operation on that integer. After that, I am checking if a HashMap is containing this Integer => If it contains this integer, I increment the integer and recheck if HashMap contains new integer until the integer is not present in HashMap. If it does not contain integer, I add integer to HashMap.

I added my code below. The code between 'start' and 'end' comments takes too long. 
If I `comment` this code between 'start' and 'end', it executes in less than a second.
So, the time is not consumed in `Random.nextInt()` or `HashMap.containsKey()`

*MyProgram.java*

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Random;

public class MyProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long total = 0;
        int randomInt;
        int count = 100000;
        int divider = 3;
        Random random = new Random();   

        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        for(int i=0; i < count; i++){

            randomInt = random.nextInt(count);

            // start
            int value1 = randomInt / divider;
            int value2 = (randomInt % divider != 0) ? 1 : 0;
            randomInt = value1 + value2;
            // end

            while(map.containsKey(randomInt)){
                randomInt++;
            }

            map.put(randomInt, 0);  // don't care about value
            total += randomInt;
        }

        System.out.println("Total : " + total);
    }
}
```

This implementation takes more than 30 seconds.

I can use List, Arrays, ArrayLists etc.. if you think they are fast. Please explain with an example.

Comment: you don't need to check if the map already contains the key as you don't care about the value. You could try to keep pushing random keys until you got `count` keys in your map. Not sure that would be quicker, but give it a try

Comment: What takes the time is probably the boxing of the integer. Perhaps you should create a mutable integer type and use that. Also, instead of your `value1` and `value2` calculation, you could use `randomInt = (random.nextInt(count) + divider - 1) / divider`

Comment: If your key exists, then HashMap will replace the previous  value with the new value for the same key. Since, you don't care about the value, you don't need to run that while loop to make the key different

Comment: @sonnet are you sure, do you mean if HashMap contains 17th key, it will automatically store it in '17+1'th key?

Comment: I mean, if your key (randomInt) is 17, and if it already exists in the map and if you put 17 again in the map, then the map will replace whatever value was saved against 17 and replace it with the new value. You are keeping the same value 0 for all keys. Also, I just ran your code and observed that the while loop takes all the time. I commented it out and the program ran in ~ 2 secs

Comment: Also, if you really don't care about the values, you can use a `HashSet<Integer>` instead of a `HashMap`

Comment: the explanation to your performance loss is the number of times you are executing `containsKey`, which will be greater when numbers are repeated, which will be greater when performing that arithmetic.

Comment: Can I somehow make it increment the randomInt, if it exists in the HashMap, without using `containsKey()`. I thought `containsKey()` is O(1) complexity?

Comment: @PatrickParker Your solution worked, please undelete your answer. I changed `[count * 10]` just for safety.

Comment: @rupinderjeet thanks, but it is an inferior approach and you should use the BitSet instead. that's why I deleted it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you don't care about the value stored in the map, but rather just the integer key, just use a `BitSet`:

- Replace the map with a `BitSet` of appropriate size:

  ```
  BitSet bits = new BitSet(count);
  ```
- Use the `nextClearBit` method to find the next unset bit:

  ```
  randomInt = bits.nextClearBit(randomInt);
  ```
- Then set that bit:

  ```
  bits.set(randomInt);
  ```

This finishes very quickly for me (0.16s, in Ideone): [<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/NdsYVQ).

---

I haven't measured it, but I would guess the main reason for the slowness of OP's code is the implicit object creation in the line:

```
while(map.containsKey(randomInt)){
```

Because maps contain references, `randomInt` has to be boxed to an `Integer`; only ints in the range -128 to 127 are guaranteed to be cached, so this will result in very large numbers of objects being created.  `BitSet` avoids creating objects because it operates on primitive `int`s.

This is discussed in *Effective Java 2nd Ed* Item 5: "Avoid creating unnecessary objects" (look for the bit where it says "Hideously slow program!").

Comment: can you read comments on other answers and still say this will work?

Comment: Which particular comments and answers are you referring to? Does the demo link not do what you expect? Note that this doesn't actually functionally change the code, it just uses a different data structure on which the operations you are using are much more efficient.

Comment: @PatrickParker indeed they can. So what? This isn't a functional change from OP's code.

Comment: @rupinderjeet the constructor is passed an initial size and the BitSet can grow as needed. this is the right answer.

Comment: You are right. Both of your solutions work for me. Thanks for referring related topic on Book.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't with the division-code as such, the problem is that you are generating much more collisions becaus you generate a smaller range for `randomInt` before trying to insert into `map`.

If you take a look at the following variation of your code

```
        for(int i=0; i < count; i++){

            randomInt = random.nextInt(33333);

            // start
//            int value1 = randomInt / divider;
//            int value2 = (randomInt % divider != 0) ? 1 : 0;
//            randomInt = value1 + value2;
            // end

            while(map.containsKey(randomInt)){
                randomInt++;
            }

            map.put(randomInt, 0);  // don't care about value
            total += randomInt;
        }
```

you will see that it takes about the same time as the code doing the divisions. So you should think over your insertion-strategy to see if you can improve that. (I can't help you with that since I have not fully understood what you are trying to achieve with your code).

Comment: You mean `value1 + value2` is a smaller value, and it creates a lot of collisions. right? But, I need to perform this operation on this random integer.

Comment: The problem is not that you are performing some operations on the random integer but that you are generating 666666 guaranteed collisions (most probably more). I have thought of a variation that might perform faster, I'll edit the post later on.

Comment: OK, my idea brought some improvement but not on the scale I hoped for, so I'll just leave it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the inner `while(map.containsKey(randomInt))` loop running for at least 3 Billion times (Look at the value of `Entered` variable in the output pasted below) due to huge collisions with the final number that gets generated after your calculation.

```
int value1 = randomInt / divider;
int value2 = (randomInt % divider != 0) ? 1 : 0;
randomInt = value1 + value2;
```

This code generates a lot of common values when looped for `100000` times and along with Auto-Boxing this could result in a performance issue.

You can check the amount of time the while loop is executed when collisions occur.

```
int randomInt;
int count = 100000;
int divider = 3;
long entered = 0;
Random random = new Random();   

HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

for(int i=0; i < count; i++){

    randomInt = random.nextInt(count);

    // start
    int value1 = randomInt / divider;
    int value2 = (randomInt % divider != 0) ? 1 : 0;
    randomInt = value1 + value2;
    // end

    while(map.containsKey(randomInt)){
        entered++;
        randomInt++;
    }

    map.put(randomInt, 0);  // don't care about value
    total += randomInt;
}

System.out.println("Total : " + total);
System.out.println("Entered : " + entered);
```

**Output :**

```
Total : 4999950000
Entered : 3335662228
```

So you should revisit the logic of `value1+value2` and rather use just `random.nextInt(count)` and  give the count the range within which you want to generate.

```
randomInt = random.nextInt(count);
while(map.containsKey(randomInt)){
    randomInt = random.nextInt(count);
}
```

Comment: your solution is not an option. I use `random.nextInt()` for testing. All the `randomInt`, `count` values are predefined in a file. I am allowed to increment `randomInt` from file by One if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

A few trivial things:

- use HashSet<> instead of Map, if you don't care about a value.
- replace the part between comments with: `randomInt = (randomInt + divider - 1) / divider`;

These are minor things, but the part between the comments is not likely to be the major contributor to your performance issues.

Because you're generating 100K numbers in the range 0 <= n < 100K, your values are going to be very dense, so I expect you'll be iterating on the while quite a bit. You would probably be better of maintaining an array of Intervals as follows:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;

class Interval {
  int min, max;
  public Interval(int min, int max) {
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "[" + min + "," + max + "]";
  }
}

public class MyProgram {
  private static void checkConsistency(Interval[] intv) {
    for(int i=0; i<intv.length; i++) {
      Interval v = intv[i];
      if (v != null && (i < v.min || i > v.max)) {
        throw new Error(i + " -> " + v);
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long total = 0;
    int randomInt;
    int count = 100000;
    int divider = 3;
    Random random = new Random();
    HashSet<Integer> hs = new HashSet<>();
    Interval[] data = new Interval[count];

    for(int i=0; i < count; i++){
        randomInt = random.nextInt(count);
        // start
        randomInt = (randomInt + divider -1) / divider;
        // end
        Interval intv = data[randomInt];
        if (intv != null) {
          randomInt = intv.max + 1;
        }
        int idx = randomInt < count ? randomInt : count - 1;
        hs.add(randomInt);
        Interval pre = randomInt > 0 ? data[randomInt-1] : null;
        Interval post = randomInt < count-1 ? data[randomInt+1] : null;
        if (pre == null && post == null) {
          data[idx] = new Interval(randomInt, randomInt);
        } else if (pre != null && post != null) {
          if (pre.max-pre.min < post.max-post.min) {
            for (int j=pre.min; j <= pre.max; j++) {
              data[j] = post;
            }
            data[idx] = post;
          } else {
            for (int j=post.min; j <= post.max; j++) {
              data[j] = pre;
            }
            data[idx] = pre;
          }
          data[idx].min = pre.min;
          data[idx].max = post.max;
        } else if (pre != null) {
          data[idx] = pre;
          data[idx].max = randomInt;
        } else {
          data[idx] = post;
          data[idx].min = randomInt;
        }
        // just for verifying consistency
        checkConsistency(data);
        total += randomInt;
    }
      System.out.println("Total : " + total);
  }
}
```

Comment: I chose the BitSet approach in another answer. But, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the values (and of course, if you don't need it in your program), use a `HashSet` instead of a `HashMap`. It has the same behavior as the HashMap key list. There can't be duplicated values.

That means if your set already contains the value `102` and the next random integer generated is also `102`, adding it to the set will do nothing. (For a Hashmap, it will just replace the key/value pair, but if your value is always 0, it won't be noticeable).

Thus, you don't need to check if your set contains the new random int and this part become useless:

```
while(map.containsKey(randomInt)){
            randomInt++;
}
```

Plus, this part is time consumming as `containsKey` loop on the map, hence you can loop a loooots of time when there are many keys in your map (what happens if the incremented value is also in the list? and the next incremented value? and so on?).
That should makes you program a lot faster.

Now you can still optimize your code by removing the declaration of `value1` and `value2` but the time consumption is way lower than your `while`loop so that probably won't make a big difference.

In the end, your code should looks like:

```
int randomInt;
int count = 100000;
int divider = 3;
Random random = new Random();   

HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();

while(set.size()<count){

    randomInt = random.nextInt(count);

    // start
    map.add((randomInt/divider) + ((randomInt % divider != 0) ? 1 : 0));
    // end
}
```

Comment: If HashSet contains `randomInt`, it will not insert it in HashSet. I need HashSet to increment `randomInt` and retry inserting. If it again contains new `randomInt`, I need to increment `randomInt` again and retry inserting. and so on.. until incremented `randomInt` is not present in HashSet.

Comment: you should write in your question that you **need** to increment the value. As it is currently written, it's looks more like you are describing a fix attempt than a requirement.

Comment: Since this is a `HashMap`  `containsKey()` will not iterate over all the values in the map, only over those that happen to be in the same hash-bucket. So appropriate sizing of the `HashMap` might bring some performance-improvements...